# Java Wildcard-types vs Kotlin Star-projection

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, wildcard

I was reading a kotlin documentation about differences between Java and Kotlin here
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html. It was stated there that **Kotlin does not have wildcard-types**. However after reading carefully through the documentation of generics I have found information about 
[star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) and honestly I can't see the difference. Can somebody explain to me how this

```
List<?> list;
```

differs from this

```
lateinit var list: MutableList<*>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably what it means is that Kotlin doesn't have wildcards in the same form as they are present in Java. Instead, Kotlin uses a different concept of [mixed-site variance](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ross/publications/mixedsite/), which adds an option to specify the variance at declaration-site, that is something you cannot do with Java wildcards.

As to the star-projection, it is actually almost equivalent to an unbounded Java wildcard. However, there is at least one difference related to the Kotlin type system.

When you have a `List<?>`, the type is unknown to Java, but all Java referential types are nullable, and therefore you can safely pass a `null` as an argument of the unknown type, e.g. `list.add(null)`.

In Kotlin that is not true, a star projection `MutableList<*>` combines both `out Any?` and `in Nothing` projections, and the latter means that you cannot pass anything at all to the methods where the type is unknown (`Nothing` is the type that has no value).

The same can be said of the out-projections: while you can pass a `null` as a Java bounded wildcard type `? extends T`, you cannot do the same with Kotlin `out T` projection.

And the exact equivalent of the Java unbounded wildcard is `<in Nothing?>`, because it lets you pass a `null` as an argument of the unknown type (`Nothing?` is `Nothing` ∪ { `null` }, this is the type that has only `null` value).