# Class<?> clazz in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

How does `Class<?> clazz` look like in Kotlin ?

I'm trying to translate this method to Kotlin code and it seems like I'm stuck.

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun isServiceRunning(context: Context, serviceClass : Class<Any>) : Boolean
```

something like that should do the job

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as

```
companion object {
    fun isServiceRunning(context: Context, serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean  { /* ... */ }
}
```

The `Class<*>` [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) is [almost equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520368/java-wildcard-types-vs-kotlin-star-projection) to the Java unbounded wildcard `Class<?>`.